# Learning from the measurements taken from a single individual

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

Suppose we take repeated measurements of $x$ and $y$ from an individual (or possibly two) and we want to estimate the effect of $x$ on $y$. For example we could simulate such data as below:

```
x1 = sample(1:100,100)
x2 = sample(1:100,100)


y1 =  1 * x1 + rnorm(100,0,20)
y2 =  1.5 * x2 + rnorm(100,0,20)

df = data.frame(y = c(y1,y2), 
                x = c(x1,x2), 
                participant = c(rep(1,100), rep(2,100)))

plot(df$x, df$y)
```

So the first 100 observations are taken from individual #1 and the rest from individual #2 and the data look like this:

[image]

Now the questions are:

1. What is the real sample size? Is it only 2 because we have only two
   individuals or we know more than that because we have repeated
   measurements from the individuals?
2. How can we update our knowledge about the effect of $x$ on $y$ using such data? If
   we fit a simple linear regression as if we have 200
   independent samples then we are certainly underestimating the uncertainty
   in the effect. So what would be the alternative approach for getting
   the most out of such a dataset to properly estimate the effect and
   account for the uncertainty in the estimate?

If you could answer in Bayesian terms that would be great but frequentist approach could also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I could come up with is using a hierarchical structure as follows:

$$y_{i,j} \sim N(\beta_{j} x_{i}, \sigma^2)$$ for observation $i$ associated with participanst $j$ and then informing the population slope through the individual slopes using a hierarchical structure:
$$\beta_{j} \sim N(\beta_{population}, \sigma_{p}^2)$$

First we have to assume some prior for $\beta_{population}$ which is the parameter of our interest (relationship between $x$ and $y$ in the population). We can fit this model easily using JAGS in R as follows:

```
# Simulating data
# Assuming only two individuals but it also works with a single one

x1 = sample(1:100,100)
x2 = sample(1:100,100)


y1 =  1 * x1 + rnorm(100,0,20)
y2 =  1.5 * x2 + rnorm(100,0,20)

df = data.frame(y = c(y1,y2), 
                x = c(x1,x2), 
                participant = c(rep(1,100), rep(2,100)))


# ------- Model definition -------------
model_code <- "
model
{
  # Likelihood
  for (i in 1:n) {
    y[i] ~ dnorm(beta[participant[i]] * x[i], sigma^-2)
  }
  
  for (i in 1:m){
    beta[i] ~ dnorm(beta_p, 100^-2)
  }
  
  # Priors
  sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
  beta_p ~ dnorm(0, 100^-2)
}
"


# Set up the data
model_data <- list(n = nrow(df), y = df$y, x = df$x, participant = df$participant, m = length(unique(df$participant)))

# Choose the parameters to watch
model_parameters <- c('beta_p')

# Run the model
model_run <- jags(
  data = model_data,
  parameters.to.save = model_parameters,
  model.file = textConnection(model_code),
  n.chains = 4, # Number of MCMC chains
  n.iter = 1000, # Number of iterations
  n.burnin = 200, # Number of iterations to remove at start
  n.thin = 2 # Amount of thinning
) 


print(model_run)
```

which gives the following posterior of the $\beta_{population}$ parameter:

```
> print(model_run)

Inference for Bugs model at "4", fit using jags,
 4 chains, each with 1000 iterations (first 200 discarded), n.thin = 2
 n.sims = 1600 iterations saved
          mu.vect sd.vect     2.5%      25%      50%      75%    97.5%  Rhat n.eff
beta_p      0.105  56.571 -110.369  -38.158   -0.428   40.821  109.098 1.002  1500
```

We can see that having 100 observations for each individual does not really help with estimating the population slope with only two individuals. If we have fitted a simple linear regression or even a random intercept model with fixed effect on the slope we would have underestimated the uncertainty significantly.